# What exactly is the process for creating a GUI for Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am new really new to Android development.

I am trying to set up a GUI for an Android App with Eclipse.

When I add components to the GUI such as a button, a yellow triangle with exclamation point appears with the message: `[I18N] Hardcoded string "Button", should use @string resource`.

Eclipse prompts me to auto-fix this by creating a string button on the string resource, but it still throws an error saying the attribute android:text already contains a string reference.

I also have the errors:

```
Couldn't resolve resource @string/name
Couldn't resolve resource @string/gps
Couldn't resolve resource @string/photo
Couldn't resolve resource @string/back
Couldn't resolve resource @string/add
```

What does Couldn't resolve resource mean? name/gps/photo/add are components in my GUI.

How do I:

`Add Components to a GUI without erroring?  I want to rename the GUI components to something relevant so I can reference them in my code. What steps are generally required?`

I have used Visual Studio before and generally only had to drag and drop components, then rename them under properties. I want to do the same thing for my Android App - please help!

Edit: I think these values are declared in my strings xml file. Here it is:

```
<string name="app_name">UCLocationSearch</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="back_button">Back Button</string>
<string name="exit">Exit<string name="add">Add</string>
<string name="gps">GPS</string>
<string name="name">Name</string>
<string name="autocompletetextview">AutoCompleteTextView</string>
<string name="photo">Photo</string>
<string name="back">Back</string>
```

Comment: [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)

Comment: You seem to be making a few mistakes while naming the GUI components. Follow a couple Android tutorials before trying your hand at the GUI editor in order to learn the basics.

Comment: Are those variables declared in your string xml in the values folder?

Comment: @SteveP. thanks for the tutorial! I think so - here is my strings xml:

Answer (score 4):

First of all using the WYSISWYG GUI for Android sucks. I prefer to create UI via the XML and rarely use the GUI editor. It's unreliable and doesn't look the same as a device. Some might disagree, but that is just my opinion.

Second, the reason you are getting the error is because in your Android project there is a file named `Strings`. This is where string definitions are kept. It looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">WPAConfiguration</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

</resources>
```

So when you call `Android:text=@string/hello_world` you get "Hello World!".

To fix the errors:

```
Couldn't resolve resource @string/name
Couldn't resolve resource @string/gps
Couldn't resolve resource @string/photo
Couldn't resolve resource @string/back
Couldn't resolve resource @string/add
```

You add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="back">Back</string>
    <string name="photo">Photo</string>
    <string name="add">Add</string>
    etc...
</resources>
```

to your `Strings` resource.

Android protocols suggest that when you are naming a button, or other GUI object, you do it via the `Strings` resource. I'd go through a couple tutorials, as others have recommended before embarking on the voyage you are. If you don't, you are going to have much more trouble than you are now.

Good luck!

Comment: Do I make the string resource first, before creating the button?

Comment: Think of the string resource as a centralized location for all string variables that are used in the UI. You just need to define it before you compile and run. Doesn't matter which is created first, so long as it gets done.

Comment: Typo: you get "Hello World!" not "Hello World".